# How to change refresh rate by adb command

Tags: android, shell, adb

I got information about device resolution, refresh rate and other info by adb command -

```
adb shell dumpsys display
```

After entering above command info retrieved is -

```
mDisplayInfos=
      PhysicalDisplayInfo{720 x 1280, 57.0 fps, density 1.5, 309.966 x 312.615 dpi, secure true, appVsyncOffset 1000000, bufferDeadline 17543860}
```

I wanted to change refresh rate to **60 fps** which is recommended.
How do I change it from *adb shell* command?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is natively supported on every mobile phone due kernel difference.

For example :

1. Using my Samsung Galaxy S5(Marshmallow), running the below command doesn't not change the original 60HZ to 90HZ

   ```
   adb shell settings put global 6ecb9657_screen_refresh_rate 0
   ```
2. Using my OnePlus 7 Pro(OxygenOS), running the below command sets the refresh rate to 90 :

   ```
   adb shell settings put global oneplus_screen_refresh_rate 0
   ```

   - Using mode 0 enables 90Hz

From the above test, I believe this is something you can achieve using custom kernels.